# Passing values between two "totally different" pages

Tags: c#, asp.net

To be clear, the two pages are only logically related in other words the values in my FirstPage.Aspx pass values to my SecondPage.Aspx so it control components and certain attributes of the controls in my SecondPage.Aspx, the SecondPage.Aspx is not a redirect or transfer from FirstPage.Asp. sorry am so sick of reading about all the answers but the one I actually need!

Consider the firstPage contains a textBox which get a value from the user or the web admin to set his preferences about the gridView page size on the SecondPage or a Text property of a label on the SecondPage

I want to explore my options to do so

PS: I was told to use a database to store values from the first page then on the page with my Label for example I connect to the database and retrieve the value and set it to the label...is this a best practice to let the page connect every time it loads to set some values sometimes it's just an int like 5, and most of the time I'd be connecting already to the database to display some table's data in a gridView or any databound control!

### **EDIT:**

Sorry if I was a bit rude, it just hit me that I'm mainly getting the same answer that I read which is totally not my case!..and of course thanks to some of you mentioned the database solution, I hoped I could get an example or an article for my particular case since I think even it's simple but yet it's essential...

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163724.aspx

Comment: So you're saying that you've read lots of articles and found lots of the same answer to your question, but now you're asking here because you *don't like* the answer that you've found?  Sounds like you should maybe accept that the solution people are recommending might be the correct one!  I'd assume it's recommended for a reason... ;-)

Comment: OF COURSE NOT! the case with all the answers that the values get passed between 2 pages which one of em is a reaction to another (response, redirect), a master page and it's pages!   MY CASE is TWO DIFFERENT pages they aren't connected they won't point to each other, i just want a value from one of them to be set to a control on the other page and am sure there's a way am not that noob! the database is my solution after listening to many people but still there's no examples to show the best practice to apply this method, I can connect to database and all stuff, i just want an accurate example!

Comment: I have replied below, but forgot to mention one other option. If it fits your needs, you can even store persistent context in static variables. They stick around as long as Application State does. The static variable could be a dictionary or whatever. But you need to worry about it's lifetime, just so you don't hog resources indefinitely.

Comment: I think database is pretty convenient for my case, and everybody mentioned it so i think it's the best for my application
I just hoped to get examples for my certain case since it's pretty essential from my point of view!..but maybe it's as simple and plain as that ( create a table to store all the controls and the admin store the properties values, then retrieved by the control ) 
I was just afraid it would be too much pressure on the database connecting to it every time the page loads to check for the latest value set by the admin, but hay! they are the EXPERIENCE :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASP.NET framework provides several mechanisms to maintain context that lasts across several HTTP requests. The data you want accessible across calls, can be stored in this context. All you have to do is decide how long do you want this context to be maintained (because it consumes resources), and if you want this context to be available across more than one server.

1. [Application State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178594.aspx) : Which is maintained for the lifetime of the application i.e. from when the application is first loaded by ASP.NET, till it is unloaded for whatever reason.
2. [Session State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) : ASP.NET is able to identify a series of HTTP requests emanating from a specific client (IP address), close to each other in time, as a session. It can create a session context that persists across such a session, in which you can store data that is accessible to the calls in the session. The session state can be made available [across server boundaries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx) by associating it with a DB or shared memory.
3. Database
4. [Viewstate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx) : You can use Viewstate to maintain context, but keep in mind that Viewstate is transferred over the wire for every request / response. It has been known to get quite large, specially if you use controls.
5. Cookies : Again, transferred on the wire for each request / response.

Comment: IMO, This is not a valid use of application state or view state.

Comment: Even though it's not what i'm exactly looking for but you explained all my options pretty much, my bad I was looking for the perfect answer for my case and didn't pay attention to your answer...maybe it's not the appropriate one to solve my problem but i think it's the best..as a reference to all who want to get started on this part and don't have a clue about the options
Thanks +1

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

- Session variable
- Cookie
- Database value

each one of them have their own pros and cons

If you want the value to be stored the next time they come to page 2, use a database value. if not, use a session variable.

The database value will give you a persistent value, and you can then store other such user variables there.

the session will give persistent data, but only for the browsers current session. The data will be lost if their session times out.

From all you've stated, i would assume a database value.

Comment: I'm not sure but if those are my only options, i think the database solution makes sense but how come there's no examples, articles, or any reference about such a thing, I mean almost every dynamic website needs a page (admin page) to have control over the website resources and update the data on the other pages!

Comment: @IKashef.  Pretty much every dynamic website does use a database to do that.  And there are **TONS** of example of how to connect to a database from ASP.NET!

Comment: Yes am finally down with that, and I already use one to store data, articles, users. but i didn't know that it could be the right way to store also my controls settings to change them dynamically, AM NOT THAT NOOB! am past connecting to a database :S am just after the best practice to do so....please could you read the PS in my question again maybe it could help you understand my case more!

Answer (score 2):

U can use cookies, session etc but if you want to pass something that defines the whole content of the page, like an ID of some sort, you might just want to put it in the QueryString. (ex: default.aspx?id=4)

Cons: everyone can read (or change) the value, not usable for critical data

Pros: everyone can read the value, and the link can be sent to others

Comment: I prefer this so long as the data being sent is what is defining what the other page is showing (like the database ID of the entity) but not if it is defining something like "how wide is the grid" or "is the tree expanded".  However you can use an anchor in the query string to do that (anchors are what come after the '#' in the URL)

Comment: it's simple as that, and PLEASE KEEP IN MIND!..they are two different pages, no redirecting or anything..Ex: PageOne has a label and PageAdmin has a textbox and a button...i want when the admin clicks the button the event handler of the click event to set the value of the text box to the text property of the label on the other page...and i don't think QueryString is the answer here!..it's probably database, BUT STILL! How =) !? will i connect to the database everytime PageOne loads to check the latest value in the database and set it to the label or what! seems consuming, isn't it ?

Comment: Ok, I think I may understand better now. Are you saying that it happens in "real time". i.e., admin is open, text box is changed. User also has Default.aspx open and the label changes immediately?

Comment: I think you got it right, and if by real time you mean the run time then definitely!

Comment: I just want to know, if you have a different answer for me after it got more clear to you or you don't have any updates!

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you start here: [Get Started with ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/get-started)

If I understand your question, you are looking to do [Cross Page Posting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139.aspx). If one page isn't posting to a 2nd, you'll need to persist the data somehow (database, session, xml file, etc). But, from reading your question, you sound like you just want to cross page post...

Comment: Actually it's not what it sounds like, the first page doesn't directly post to the other page

for example you have an admin panel with a text box and you want to control another page's label control..it doesn't make since that after the web admin change the value, it redirects to the second page to make this change, instead it should take the value and pass it to the other page which is my problem here, without redirecting to it or anything

i think i might need to use a DB to store the admin preferences permanently until he decides to change them again, but i need example on how to do that

Comment: then you'll need the persistence part. DB, XML, Flat File, etc.

Comment: Check that link above on how to get started. It gets into depth on persisting to a DB

Comment: "and most of the time I'd be connecting already to the database to display some table's data in a gridView or any databound control!" does that sound like I need to read that!....am okay with database and connection and commands and all stuff!...I just want a good example to be precise Admin Page and A Default.aspx...the admin takes a value from a textbox in the page and sets the label on the Default.aspx to it!

Comment: Don't sound so defensive. Trying to help. All an admin page is is a form that saves data to the database. The text box writes it, the label reads it.

Comment: Am just tired trying getting people to understand me!..and I failed this time!...anyway my bad Bryce, THANKS for your effort

Answer (score 0):

I think the better answer is "Control State"

Reference : http://www.asp.net/general/videos/how-do-i-use-control-state-to-persist-information-for-a-custom-web-server-control

but I couldn't get this implemented on my case, two different pages
for example : the web user control is placed on News.aspx and the textbox which will have the value to be assigned to the control on News.aspx is placed in myAdmin.aspx page!

and to be honest, I didn't quite understand the code

So! do you think this is the best solution ? if yes do you think It can be used for my case (two different pages) ??

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very confusing, took me a lot of time before I could I understand what you actually need. Since there is no events in HTML, you will need to use JavaScript and some kind of web-service (AJAX).

Page A will store the value in database, and JavaScript on page B will constantly check database for new values, get them and output to the user. In order to that it needs to connect to some webservice/webmethod that will return the value from database to your page. A good example can be found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/AjaxJQuerySample.aspx).

Alternatively you can refresh page every 5 seconds using

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" content="5">
```

and check for the new database value on `Page_Load` server event.

Comment: Sorry about that! but doing the javaScript thing will make it like the facebook instant notification module, right ?               

and btw I don't think I'll need that! i'll just need to check for the value in the database just one time, when the page loads! and I was just trying to save my control's attributes like using ControlState instead of storing the values in a database!

Comment: If you want user to store his preferences it is better to use session or cookies, if you want admin to set them for everyone or particular user then you have to use a database.